# What is the difference between these snippets to find prime numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the prime numbers between 1 and 100.

I know there must be a million ways to achieve this, but I wrote a few lines, probably quite dumb.

```
pnumber = []
for x in range(2, 101):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if all(x % i):
            pnumber.append(x)
print(pnumber)
```

This won't work, but if I try this code, it works.

```
pnumber = [x for x in range(2, 101) if all(x % i for i in range(2, x))]
print(pnumber)
```

What is wrong with the first try? Isn't it a dumb way of writing the second try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippets are not equivalent, the equivalent for loop (without using any generator or comprehension expressions) would be:

```
pnumber = []
for x in range(2, 101):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        pnumber.append(x)
print(pnumber)
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you!

Comment: didn't know that I can use for...else, I thought one can only use if...else

Answer (score 2):

Your first try should be:

```
pnumber = []
for x in range(2, 101):
    if all(x % i for i in range(2, x)):
        pnumber.append(x)
print(pnumber)
```

Your second try is just a one line version of the first one, which is basically the same in speed, but shorter, and is called a list comprehension. If you compare the two methods, you'll see the similarities.  
To better understand the second method, think of set notation in algebra:

```
# In algerba:
evens = {x : x mod 2 = 0}
# In python (you need a finite set of numbers for x):
evens = [x for x in range(2,10) if x%2==0]

# In algerba:
primes = {x : for any 1<y<x, x mod y =/= 0}
# In python (you need a finite set of numbers for x):
primes = [x for x in range(2, 101) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
```